# NSInvalidArgumentException: [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, nsarray

i am creating a project with tab bar application, database and segmented control in navigation control (programmatically) to display information from database and i am getting the SIGABRT with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'` in console window ..

TableViewAppDelegate.

```
#import "SegmentsController.h"
#import "TableViewAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AtoZHomePageViewController.h"
#import "CollectionRecipe.h"
#import "NSArray+PerformSelector.h" 

@interface TableViewAppDelegate()

- (NSArray *)segmentViewControllers;
- (void)firstUserExperience;
@end


@implementation TableViewAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize tabbarController;
@synthesize recipes;
@synthesize segmentsController, segmentedControl;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

    NSArray * viewControllers = [self segmentViewControllers];
   // UINavigationController * navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.segmentsController = [[SegmentsController alloc] initWithNavigationController:navigationController viewControllers:viewControllers];

    self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[viewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)]];
    self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self.segmentsController
                              action:@selector(indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


    databaseName = @"RecipeDatabase.sql";

    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    // Query the database for all animal records and construct the "animals" array
    [self readRecipesFromDatabase];

    // Configure and show the window
     [self firstUserExperience];
    [window addSubview:[tabbarController view]];
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Segment Content

- (NSArray *)segmentViewControllers {
    UIViewController * AtoZRecipe     = [[AtoZHomePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"AtoZRecipeController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController * RecipesCollection = [[CollectionRecipe alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeCollection" bundle:nil];

    NSArray * viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:AtoZRecipe, RecipesCollection, nil];
    [AtoZRecipe release]; [RecipesCollection release];

    return viewControllers;
}

- (void)firstUserExperience {
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self.segmentsController indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:self.segmentedControl];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Save data if appropriate
}
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];


}

-(void) readRecipesFromDatabase {
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init the animals Array
    recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from recipe order by name";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row
                NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *aAuthor=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,2)]; 
                NSString *aThumbnail=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,3)];
                NSString *aPre_time=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,5)];
                NSString *aBake_time=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,6)];
                NSString *aTota_ltime=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 7)];
                NSString *alarge_image=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,8)];                    
                NSString *asmall_image=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 9)]; 
                NSString *asummary=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 10)];
                NSString *aServe_size=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,11)];
                // Create a new recipe object with the data from the database
               AtoZHomePage *recipe=[[AtoZHomePage alloc] initWithName:aName author:aAuthor img_thumbnail:aThumbnail pre_Time:aPre_time bake_Time:aBake_time total_time:aTota_ltime large_Img:alarge_image small_Img:asmall_image summary:asummary serve_size:aServe_size];
                  // Add the recipe object to the recipes Array
                [recipes addObject:recipe];

                [recipe release];
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);    
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    self.segmentedControl   = nil;
    self.segmentsController = nil;
    [recipes release];
    [tabbarController release];
    [navigationController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

this line is ambiguous  `NSArray * viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:AtoZRecipe, RecipesCollection, nil];` as i saw most of the related posts and if i remove nil it will be missing sentinel and according to me i have called appropriate view controllers. 
 Please do help me to get rid off this bug... Thanks loads in advance:):)

Comment: `[recipes addObject:recipe];` this line might be the once crashing.. add a breakpoint here.. in any case add breakpoints to your coed in lots of place s and check which functions successfully passes..

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the beginning of all the methods all tell us exactly where your app stops, that will tell us how to fix it. Take into account that your code is very long, people are going to ignore your question as soon as they see so much code and no clues at all... just an advice for getting your answer faster!

Comment: ...or add a exception breakpoint and see the exact line where the problem is. Breakpoints navigator, plus sign in bottom left, add exception breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks Shubhank,tonio and jrturton for your responses... i inserted four breakpoints and its showing Thread stopped at breakpoint 8 in firstling @synthesize window;

Comment: @Shubhank: code is not reaching [recipes addObject:recipe]; , before that only SIGABRT thread is invoked...

Comment: add breakpoints to each function.. when it crash ..do note the last function's breakpoint it stopped.. then update your code...to tell only that function..we will find the error.

Comment: i added breakpoint  NSArray * viewControllers = [self segmentViewControllers]; and program stopped in self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[viewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(selectedIndex)]];

Comment: You can replace `[viewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)]` with `[viewControllers valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.title"]` to avoid the dependancy on external code.  See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16569259/296446

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your not allocating the memory to array that's the reason your getting the NSInvalidArgumentException

Try this one

```
NSArray * viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self segmentViewControllers]];
```

Comment: i tried the above code instead of NSArray * viewControllers = [self segmentViewControllers]; still same error :(